# Website on a Windows server have a subdomain on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, windows, subdomain

I have a website [zacharyhodge.com](http://zacharyhodge.com) and I would like to have a subdomain for a blog at [blog.zacharyhodge.com](http://blog.zacharyhodge.com).  Now, I enjoy working with Windows server-side technologies on my main site, but I would like to run my blog through a custom WordPress template.

Is it possible for me to have my main domain [zacharyhodge.com](http://zacharyhodge.com) on a Microsoft server, with my blog subdomain [blog.zacharyhodge.com](http://blog.zacharyhodge.com) pointing to a different server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this would be configured at the DNS level using an A record.

Point the Subdomain to your Linux server's IP.

```
subdomain.example.com. IN A 255.255.255.255
```

Comment: Please mark correct if this answer covered your question. If you are not satisfied let me know and I am happy to provide any more info you would like on this subject.