# Main website on Linux with Subdomain on Windows on SHARED hosting

Tags: hosting

Can someone please tell if this scenario is possible and how?

Main domain on Linux and subdomain Windows on a SHARED Hosting space.

One answer is given on [Website on a Windows server have a subdomain on a Linux server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/245005/website-on-a-windows-server-have-a-subdomain-on-a-linux-server) but my host provider says that it is for dedicated hosting space.

Please could anyone suggest?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. But if you want to know how to convince your hosting providers to set it up correctly, you may find you get better answers at our sister site [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks for the yes. However, a specific link to the answer for this question would have helped.

Comment: You will have to ask the question yourself. :)

Comment: My sincere apologies for my earlier (deleted) comment Michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't point domain.com/www.domain.com at one server (running Linux) and xyz.domain.com at another server running a different OS. Whether the servers are dedicated or not has nothing to do with it.

Obviously your provider would need to have Linux and Windows hosting servers and set you up a hosting account on a Linux server for domain.com/www.domain.com and set up another hosting account on a Windows server configured for xyz.domain.com

Comment: Thanks Matt! I will forward this link to my host provider and will thank you again after his reply.

Comment: Thansk Matt! He accepted it! Cheers!